# Unity 5.5.2f1 to 5.6.1f1 - interpolated strings error?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, c#-4.0

I've just updated my Unity version from 5.5.2f1 to 5.6.1f1. Suddenly I get the error:

> Feature `interpolated strings' cannot be used because it is not part
>   of the C# 4.0 language specification

The code below worked well before updating.

```
public class SensorData
{
    public int Timestamp { get; set; }
    public float Humidity { get; set; }
    public float Temp { get; set; }
    public int Light { get; set; }
    public int Button { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{Timestamp}, {Humidity}, {Temp}, {Light}, {Button}";
    }
}
```

I don't have a clue if its supposed to still work.

Comment: Unity only supports C# 4.0. I don't think your code worked before.

Comment: "interpolated strings" is a new feature from c# 6.0. i have no clue how it works in your unity 5.5.2f1, however please check the differences of project settings between 2 unity versions.

Comment: I can't tell why but it really DID work. Otherwise I wouldn't say so and thats why I am asking because it seems really weird.

Comment: Where your Settings on `.net 4.6 Experimental`? https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/upgraded-mono-net-in-editor-on-5-5-0b4.433541/

Comment: No I used .net 2.0   -> someone has the same problem: https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/no-more-string-interpolation-in-unity-5-6-1f1.471690/

Comment: The fact that it was working is a miracle. It **shouldn't**. Are you sure you were not using special version of Unity that supports >.Net .4 because Unity util supports up to .Net 3.5 at this time.

Comment: I have the same problem - he's not making things up hah. Unity somehow magically worked with string interpolation in 5.5.2f1, but not anymore since updating. I'm wondering if perhaps Unity specially implemented it as an extension to C#4.0

Comment: C# 6.0 is available if you are targeting .NET 4.6.  So, if you had altered your .csproj file to target .NET 4.6, then it would work, . . ., until the next time that Unity re-wrote the .csproj file from scratch. :(

Comment: VS 2010 defaults to C# 4.0. VS 2015 defaults to C# 6.0.  When Unity writes the .csproj file it changes what it wants changed. Unity 5.5.2f1 didn't bother to change that default because the developers were probably using 2010.  Unity 5.6.1f1 does change that default because they want to stay at C# 4.0 for their other compilers, not VS.  They all handle C# 4.0, but don't all handle C# 6.0. Yet.

Comment: I can confirm what he said about it working before. I have the exact same thing. Worked fine. Had plenty of interpolated strings. Updated from 5.* to 5.6.1. Interpolated strings are now an issue

Comment: same problem..
5.5.3p4 => 5.6.2
any solutions?

Comment: Hey, interpolated seem to still not be supported. I just "fixed" it by doing it the old way (regarding the above mentioned code).

return string.Format ("{Timestamp}, {Humidity}, {Temp}, {Light}, {Button}", Timestamp, Humidity, Temp, Light, Button);

Comment: I had the same issue. I switched from free to paid Unity and updated to 5.6.1f1 at the same time and it stopped working. Makes sense that it does not work now however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that interpolated strings are still not working after updating. To still use my above mentioned code, I did it the old way.

Instead of:

```
return $"{Timestamp}, {Humidity}, {Temp}, {Light}, {Button}";
```

I did:

```
return string.Format ("{Timestamp}, {Humidity}, {Temp}, {Light}, {Button}", Timestamp, Humidity, Temp, Light, Button);
```

Comment: It is doubtful that is the code *actually* used. It should throw `FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format`. Trivially: `string.Format("{x}", "hello")` uses an invalid format specifier, while `string.Format("{0}", "hello")` is valid.

Answer (score 0):

I have had success using

```
string.format("{0},{1},{2},{3}, {4}", Timestamp, Humidity, Temp, Light, Button);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Unity 2017 it's now possible to use interpolated strings in Unity if you change the .NET version that Unity uses.
Interpolated strings is a feature from C# 6 which is released in .NET 4.6.

To change to .NET 4.6 go to:
`Edit > Project Settings > Player`, expand "Other settings" and change the "Scripting Runtime Version" to .NET 4.6

For more info look at:
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ScriptingRuntimeUpgrade.html

In Unity 2018, Unity should use .NET 4.x by default so you should have access to interpolated strings without having to change anything.